# Serialize Steema Tee Chart DrawLine

Tags: java, teechart

When I serialize a DrawLine (https://www.steema.com/files/public/teechart/java/v1/docs/JavaDoc/com/steema/teechart/tools/DrawLine.html) that contains DrawLineItem's (https://www.steema.com/files/public/teechart/java/v1/docs/JavaDoc/index.html?com/steema/teechart/tools/DrawLines.html) then Java throws a java.io.NotSerializableException: com.steema.teechart.tools.DrawLineItem error.

The objective of DrawLine is to store DrawLineItem's and the Tee Chart documenation states that DrawLine implements java.io.Serializable, but DrawLineItem is not. Please can you assist me to serialize a DrawLine with DrawLineItems or explain why this is has been done like this because I do not see a reason why anyone would need to serialize a DrawLine that did not contain any DrawLineItems?

Alternatively; I can create my own Object with all of the relivant information if you could tell me what information in the DrawLine I need to store/restore the DrawLine and what the code is so that I can draw a DrawLine via code.

Comment: I've added this to the bug tracking system, here: http://bugs.teechart.net/show_bug.cgi?id=506